# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools not installed, ASP.net core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I am creating a simple console Application (.Net Core) application, Where I define a class called fruit and a dbcontext called FruitDbContext. I used VS2015 and SQL Server in this sample.

I was hoping vs2015 could create the database for me (code first migration?). I have installed package EntityFrameworkCore and its tools then Add-Migration for vs2015 to create the database. My sqlserver was installed locally so there is no networking issue. The Add-Migration encountered an weird Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools not installed while it was installed successfully.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.1' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer',Version='1.1.1')
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer',Version='1.1.1') 43ms
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/1.1.1
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/1.1.1 103ms
Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.1.
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.1.1.1.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.1' to ConsoleApp1
Executing nuget actions took 1.01 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.3928695
PM> Install-Package microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.0' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools',Version='1.1.0')
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools',Version='1.1.0') 79ms
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.1.0
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.1.0 105ms
Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.0.
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.1.1.0.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.0' to ConsoleApp1
Executing nuget actions took 554.65 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.8128143
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
Cannot execute this command because 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' is not installed in project 'src\ConsoleApp1'. Add 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' to the 'tools' section in project.json. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details.
```

My Json file

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.1"
            }
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to restore the package, rebuild the project but nothing was helping.

This is the structure of my project to show that I have done nothing fancy

[image]

My classes are as simple as they could be:

Fruit.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Entity
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string FruitName { get; set; }
        public string FruitColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FruitDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp1.Entity
{
    public class FruitDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionBuilder)
        {
            optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source = xxx; Database=Fruitdb; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 15; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = True; ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False");
        }
    }
}
```

I think it was not related to my classes but I listed anyway. I have tried to move the tools to its own section in the json file as suggested in other post but I still get the same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you check last line of error it says - `Add 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' to the 'tools' section in project.json`

In your `project.json`, you have added only **dependencies**. You need to add **tools** section too. Refer below sample-

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.1"
            }
    },
    "tools": {
      ....
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"  << Add respective version here
      ....
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, refer Upgrading tooling packages section [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)

Comment: I have manually added Tools in the json this time it is complaining "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" I do not remember issuing the command

Comment: @user1205746 plz check my updated answer. Also, you can refer Upgrading tooling packages section [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)

Comment: Have tried your suggestion and upgraded the package to 1.1 and even installed .NetCore 1.1 SDK. Got a different error:     The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.

Comment: @user1205746 As mentioned in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db#create-your-database), Run `Add-Migration InitialCreate` to scaffold a migration to create the initial set of tables for your model. If you receive an error stating `The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`, close and reopen Visual Studio.